# ¿Cómo alinear botones en HTML con Bootstrap 4 a la izquierda, centro y derecha?

Tags: html, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Tengo el siguiente código:

```html
<!-- Esta linea simplemente es para tener bootstrap en el ejemplo -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Fin linea CDN bootstrap -->

<div class="container-fluid h-100 " style="margin-top: 40px">
    <div class="row w-100 align-items-center">
        <div class="col text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary regular-button botones" id="guardarReceta" title="Confirma ....."> Guardar</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary regular-button botones disabled" x-id="cargarReceta" title="Carga los datos ....."> Cargar</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary regular-button botones" id="cancelarCambios" title="Deshace todos los cambios no confirmados"> Cancelar </button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger regular-button botones" id="aplicarCambios" title="Confirma todos los cambios realizados ....."> Confirmar cambios </button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger regular-button botones" id="enviarCambios" title="...."> Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Estoy intentando que los botones de "guardar" y "cancelar" queden en el centro (como están actualmente) pero el botón de enviar esté a la derecha (unos 20px antes del borde final) y los botones de "cargar" y "guardar como" queden a la izquierda (unos 20px antes del borde inicial) pero me está resultando imposible.

Edición:

Adjunto captura de pantalla del resultado de haber intentando lo que me indicaron en la primera respuesta.

[image: Captura de pantalla]

Código de la respuesta modificado para que quede como quiero:

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100 " style="margin-top: 40px">
    <!-- Left -->
    <div class="row w-100 text-left">
        <div class="col">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary regular-button botones" id="guardarReceta" title="Confirma ....."> Guardar</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary regular-button botones disabled" x-id="cargarReceta" title="Carga los datos ....."> Cargar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Center -->
    <div class="row w-100 text-center" style="margin-top:10px;">
        <div class="col">
            <button class="btn btn-primary regular-button botones" id="cancelarCambios" title="Deshace todos los cambios no confirmados"> Cancelar </button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger regular-button botones" id="aplicarCambios" title="Confirma todos los cambios realizados ....."> Confirmar cambios </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- right -->
    <div class="row w-100 text-right" style="margin-top:10px;">
        <div class="col">
            <button class="btn btn-danger regular-button botones" id="enviarCambios" title="...."> Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Tu última edición intenta responder a tu pregunta? De ser así, revierte esa edición, y _ponla como respuesta_. Recuerda que el formato de [es.so] es de _preguntas y respuestas_. Además, no olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta que te fue más útil cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo este ejemplo con `flexbox`, que he leído que estabas intentado con eso en un comentario:

```html
<!-- Esta linea simplemente es para tener bootstrap en el ejemplo -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Fin linea CDN bootstrap -->

<div class="container-fluid h-100 " style="margin-top: 40px">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row w-100 justify-content-between">
        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary regular-button botones disabled" x-id="cargarReceta" title="Carga los datos .....">Cargar</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger regular-button botones" id="aplicarCambios" title="Confirma todos los cambios realizados .....">Confirmar cambios</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary regular-button botones" id="guardarReceta" title="Confirma .....">Guardar</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary regular-button botones" id="cancelarCambios" title="Deshace todos los cambios no confirmados">Cancelar</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-danger regular-button botones" id="enviarCambios" title="....">Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Si lo prefieres sin `flebox` dimelo y te adjunto un ejemplo son ello, te dejare los dos de todas formas

Comment: Funciona perfecto, no termino de entender el código, pero va perfecto. Viendo la documentación oficial, interpreto que si utilizo únicamente "between" va a coger todos los elementos y los va a separar en distancias iguales.

Comment: Eso es, lo que pasa es que si te fijas, he creado tres `div` creando los bloques que querias, y estos son los que se separan, luego dentro de cada uno meto los botones. Tambien tienes la opcion de usar `around` en vez de `between`, esto los separa de diferente manera, mira cual te gusta mas y juega con ello.

Comment: Para dar por finalizada la pregunta vota la respuesta como respuesta correcta y agradeceria si le das un upvote :) Lo dicho, si quieres que te añada un ejemplo sin usar `Flexbox` estare encantado de hacerlo.

Comment: Lo menos que puedo hacer por ti. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

con las clases **text-left**, **text-center** y **text-right** puedes alinear los botones en tu row. Te dejo un ejemplo aquí abajo.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
<div class="container-fluid h-100 " style="margin-top: 40px">
    <!-- Left -->
    <div class="row w-100 text-left">
        <div class="col">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary regular-button botones" id="guardarReceta" title="Confirma ....."> Guardar</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary regular-button botones disabled" x-id="cargarReceta" title="Carga los datos ....."> Cargar</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary regular-button botones" id="cancelarCambios" title="Deshace todos los cambios no confirmados"> Cancelar </button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger regular-button botones" id="aplicarCambios" title="Confirma todos los cambios realizados ....."> Confirmar cambios </button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger regular-button botones" id="enviarCambios" title="...."> Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Center -->
    <div class="row w-100 text-center" style="margin-top:10px;">
        <div class="col">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary regular-button botones" id="guardarReceta" title="Confirma ....."> Guardar</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary regular-button botones disabled" x-id="cargarReceta" title="Carga los datos ....."> Cargar</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary regular-button botones" id="cancelarCambios" title="Deshace todos los cambios no confirmados"> Cancelar </button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger regular-button botones" id="aplicarCambios" title="Confirma todos los cambios realizados ....."> Confirmar cambios </button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger regular-button botones" id="enviarCambios" title="...."> Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- right -->
    <div class="row w-100 text-right" style="margin-top:10px;">
        <div class="col">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary regular-button botones" id="guardarReceta" title="Confirma ....."> Guardar</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary regular-button botones disabled" x-id="cargarReceta" title="Carga los datos ....."> Cargar</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary regular-button botones" id="cancelarCambios" title="Deshace todos los cambios no confirmados"> Cancelar </button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger regular-button botones" id="aplicarCambios" title="Confirma todos los cambios realizados ....."> Confirmar cambios </button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger regular-button botones" id="enviarCambios" title="...."> Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<body/>
<html/>
```

Comment: yo estaba intentando con "d-flex justify-content-start", "d-flex justify-content-center", etc. Link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Comment: El único problema que veo es que utilizo tu código y elimino algunos botones del "centro", algunos de la izquierda y algunos de la derecha, no me quedan en la misma fila. Voy a subir una captura de pantalla (editaré la pregunta).

Comment: si te das cuenta he echo una row por cada tipo de alineacion hazlo en columnas i te saldra si lo quieres todo en una misma fila

Comment: He probado pero no me ha quedado bien: https://codepen.io/i7strelok/pen/poamZzQ. También he probado quitar los "div=col" pero el resultado es el mismo